# 3 tables and 2 left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

## Query 1:

```
SELECT sum(total_revenue_usd)  
  FROM table1 c 
 WHERE c.irt1_search_campaign_id IN (
       SELECT assign_id 
         FROM table2 ga 
                        LEFT JOIN table3 d
                                  ON d.campaign_id = ga.assign_id 
       )
```

## Query 2:

```
SELECT sum(total_revenue_usd) 
  FROM table1 c 
                LEFT JOIN table2 ga 
                          ON c.irt1_search_campaign_id = ga.assign_id 
                LEFT JOIN table3 d 
                          ON d.campaign_id = ga.assign_id
```

Query 1 gives me the correct result where as I need it in the second style without using 'in'. However Query 2 doesn't give the same result.

How can I change the first query without using 'in' ?

The reason being is that the small query is part of a much larger query, there are other conditions that won't work with 'in'

Comment: isnt' it enough to use JOIN instead of the first LEFT JOIN?

Comment: can there be multiple rows in table2 with the same assign_id ?

Comment: What are these other conditions which don't work with `IN` ?

Comment: so the is another column that must match an outer query but it can't if it's inside the IN

Comment: @marcosh - JOIN is short for INNER JOIN not LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of

```
SELECT sum(total_revenue_usd)  
FROM table1 c 
JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ga.assign_id 
  FROM table2 ga 
  JOIN table3 d 
  ON d.campaign_id = ga.assign_id 
) x
ON c.irt1_search_campaign_id = x.assign_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries do very different things:

The first query sums the total_revenue_usd from table1 where irt1_search_campaign_id exists in table2 as assign_id. (The outer join to table3 is absolutely unnecessary, by the way, because it doesn't change wether a table2.assign_id exists or not.) As you look for *existence* in table2, you can of course replace IN with EXISTS.

The second query gets you combinations of table1, table2 and table3. So, in case there are two records in table2 for an entry in table1 and three records in table3 for each of the two table2 records, you will get six records for the one table1 record. Thus you sum its total_revenue_usd sixfold. This is not what you want. Don't join table1 with the other tables.

EDIT: Here is the query using an exists clause. As mentioned, outer joining table3 doesn't alter the results.

```
Select sum(total_revenue_usd)  
from table1 c 
where exists
(
  select *
  from table2 ga
  -- left join table3 d on d.campaign_id = ga.assign_id 
  where ga.assign_id = c.irt1_search_campaign_id
);
```